# Is there a way to simplify match directly for Ok("VAL") in Result<String, VarError>

Tags: rust

I have this code:

```
let routes = match env::var("ENV") {
    Ok(el) => {
        if el == "PROD" {
            routes![upload_image]
        } else {
            routes![get_token, callback, form, upload_image, refresh]
        }
    },
    _ => routes![get_token, callback, form, upload_image, refresh],
};
```

The function `env::var` returns a `Result<String, VarError>`. I was wondering if my above code could be simplified like this:

```
let routes = match env::var("ENV") { // E: mismatched types: this expression has type `Result<std::string::String, VarError>
    Ok("PROD") => { // E: mismatched types: expected `String`, found `&str`
       routes![upload_image]
    },
    _ => routes![get_token, callback, form, upload_image, refresh],
};
```

However, I am getting an error about "mismatched types: expected `String`, found `&str`". Is there a way to simplify this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The probably simplest solution is to just use the fact that `String` [derefs to `str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-Deref-for-String) and call [`Result::as_deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.as_deref):

```rust
fn main() {
    let routes = match std::env::var("ENV").as_deref() {
        Ok("PROD") => {
           "prod_routes"
        },
        _ => "fallback_routes",
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple `if` expression instead of pattern matching and use `to_string()` to construct a `Result` value that is directly comparable:

```
let routes = if env::var("ENV") == Ok("PROD".to_string()) {
   routes![upload_image]
} else {
   routes![get_token, callback, form, upload_image, refresh]
};
```

(Or use `env::var("ENV").as_deref() == Ok("PROD")`, see the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76920071).)

With pattern matching, you can also use a [*match guard*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#extra-conditionals-with-match-guards) to avoid `to_string()` and `as_deref()`:

```
let routes = match env::var("ENV") {
    Ok(s) if s == "PROD" => {
       routes![upload_image]
    },
    _ => routes![get_token, callback, form, upload_image, refresh],
};
```